Uncontrolled shutting down of Ecipse IDE on Zorin OS
Eclipse randomly closes whenever I try to modify a code.
I opened a project I was working on and I was expecting the IDE to funtion normally without randomly closing. I tried updating the IDE and JDK but the issue persisted.

Have you checked the eclipse log file?


Check eclipse logs
Check dmesg


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Tried all that and when I try to solve any of the issues explained, nothing changes
